# Find the number of ways 10 balls can be chosen given that one red and one blue ball are selected from each box

Tags: combinatorics, probability-distributions, permutations, combinations

Consider 4 boxes, where each box contains 3 red balls and 2 blue balls. Assume that all 20 balls are distinct. In how many different ways can 10 balls be chosen from these 4 boxes so that from each box at least one red ball and one blue ball are chosen ?

I tried it in the following way

10 balls need to be selected( one red and one blue ball from every box):

That leaves us with only three options

5 Red +5 Blue

4 Red+ 6Blue

6 Red+4 Blue

3 ways of selecting one red ball from one box
3^4 for four boxes=81

2 ways of selecting one blue ball from one box
2^4 for four boxes=16

Hence we selected the 8 balls according to the condition
We are left with 2 more selections, we can choose any 2out of the remaining 12 balls
so 12C2=66

= 81* 16* 66
=85536

But the answer is 21816
What did i do wrong?

Comment: in case 1) you take 2 2 2 4 [rb rb rb and rbrb /rrrrr /bbbb /bbbr /brrr /rbrr]


in case 2) you take 2 2 3 3 [rb rb rb and rrr/bbb/rrb/rbb]

Comment: your calculating will basically be $4c_1(3c1 2c1)^3(5c_4)$ + $4c_2 (3c1 2c1)^2(3c_3-1)^2$ = 21816

Comment: In your process, you choose 8 balls, and THEN you choose the 2 remaining balls. If X and Y are 2 balls with same characteristics (same color, same box), you consider that X then Y, or Y then X, it is 2 different cases. You should consider it is only 1 case. You cannot organize your calcul like this.

Comment: I've added an answer to the first of the dupes that is (in my humble opinion) considerably simpler than the other answers.  It's organized by the two possible patterns of balls selected from boxes, either $4222$ or $3322$.

Answer (score 1):

You need to do case by case *in totality*, you can't *fractionate* the choices into $8$ first and then $2$

With exponents denoting numbers chosen, possibilities, to give a couple of examples, will be like

$R^3B\;RB\; RB\; RB:\; \binom41\times [\binom33\binom21]\times[\binom31\binom21]^3 =1728$

$R^2B\;R^2B\;RB\;RB: \; \binom42\times[\binom32\binom21]^2\times [\binom31\binom21]^2 = 7776$

Proceed similarly for other cases, and you should arrive at the correct answer

Comment: I've added an answer to the first of the dupes that is (in my humble opinion) considerably simpler than the other answers.  It's organized by the two possible patterns of balls selected from boxes, either $4222$ or $3322$.

Comment: More power to you ! $\;\;$ :)